# Date Component Manipulation

Tags: date, datetime, excel, vba

Is it possible to manipulate the components, such as `year`, `month`, `day` of a `date` in VBA?  I would like a function that, given a day, a month, and a year, returns the corresponding date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateSerial(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)
```

would be what you are looking for.

`DateSerial(2008, 8, 19)` returns `8/19/2008`

Answer (score 2):

There are several date functions in VBA - check this [site](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html)

DateSerial(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)

Answer (score 2):

You want [DateSerial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c(VS.80).aspx):

```
Dim someDate As Date = DateSerial(year, month, day)
```